# Fibrations are thought of as epimorphisms

Tags: category-theory, model-categories, fibration, monomorphisms, epimorphisms

In the book [More concise algebraic topology](http://93.174.95.29/main/777000/ddfc2047caa0b61498913365e9f6dfb4/%28Chicago%20Lectures%20in%20Mathematics%29%20K.%20Ponto%2C%20J.%20P.%20May%20-%20More%20Concise%20Algebraic%20Topology_%20Localization%2C%20Completion%2C%20and%20Model%20Categories%20%28Chicago%20Lectures%20in%20Mathematics%29%20%20-University%20Of%20Chicago%20Press%20.pdf) on the page 213 they write

> We think of fibrations as analogous to epimorphisms.

BUT [Hovey](http://93.174.95.29/main/3000/229756633ef1a320bed3109b1ac1ab52/%28Mathematical%20surveys%20and%20monographs%2063%29%20Mark%20Hovey%20-%20Model%20categories-American%20Mathematical%20Society%20%281999%29.pdf) on the page 51 says
$f$ is a fibration if it is in $J-inj$.
My question is simple: how **epimorphisms** (rather than **monomorphisms**) are all of $J-inj$ ? I.e. how can $J-inj$ be thought of as **epis**?

Comment: What is $J$ here?

Comment: @Berci it is as in Hovey page $50$: "and define the set $J$ to consist
of the inclusions $D^n \to D^n \times I$ which take $x$ to $(x, 0)$, for $n \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If you read definition 2.1.7 of Hovey you see that $J$-inj is the maps with the RLP with respect to the maps in $J$. These should remind with $J$ being the inclusions $D^n\to D^n\times I$. One example of such maps are covering maps, these we would definitely want to be surjective.